# BCP syntax error in sybase

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I'm running a bcp code through command line which looks similar to the below

```
bcp  tempdb..temptable out output.txt -S Servername -i, -U username –P pword –r \n  -t
```

each time I do I get and error saying "Syntax Error in 'úP' 
If I remove everything after the username i am able to get the code to work as I am prompted for the password however it gives the table in a format which is imposssible to use.

could anyone advise where the syntax error may be occuring?

Comment: It might be helpful to know the format of the file you are trying to create as well (csv,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it appears you have a few issues.

1. `-i` is not a valid option
2. `-t` should specify a field delimeter
3. You haven't specified a mode (character or native) (-c or -n)

Assuming you are trying to create a csv, here's what you may be looking for:

```
bcp tempdb..temptable out output.txt -S servername -U username -P password -c -t , -r \n
```

You may also find this page helpful from the **bcp** section of the *[Sybase ASE Utility Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/utility78.htm)*  It's from the ASE 15.5 docs, but the syntax is the same for most versions 12.0 and newer.